# Microsoft Graph: How to get "Audio Minutes", "Video Minutes" and "Screensharing Minutes" from Team Users?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

When accessing the Team Users Activity reports in Teams Admin panel (http://admin.teams.microsoft.com/), under analysis and reports there is the option to download a CSV file, that contains the following information:

- Id
- DisplayName
- EmailId
- ChannelMessages
- ReplyMessages
- PostMessages
- ChatMessages
- UrgentMessages
- MeetingsOrganized
- MeetingsParticipated
- 1:1 Calls
- GroupCalls
- AudioTime (Minutes)
- VideoTime (Minutes)
- ScreenShareTime (Minutes)
- LastActivity (UTC Time)

I need to "automate" the search for this information, and it is my understanding that the only way to do that is to user Microsoft Graph ([microsoft-graph]).

I did find some of this information by "mining" the documentation, and found this API "[getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0)", that provides:

- Report Refresh Date
- User Principal Name
- Last Activity Date
- Is Deleted
- Deleted Date
- Assigned Products
- Team Chat Message Count
- Private Chat Message Count
- Call Count
- Meeting Count
- Has Other Action
- Report Period

Also I found some useful Teams activity information under the [Team Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) APIs. However, I can't find the following information that comes in the CSV exported from Admin Teams:

- 1:1 Calls
- GroupCalls
- AudioTime (Minutes)
- VideoTime (Minutes)
- ScreenShareTime (Minutes)

I did find an API about [Calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) that **seems** do provide detailed information about a specific call record, and then I could verify it's type, and then count Audio, Video and check for Screensharing, but It asks for a call Id record, and what I need to do is to list all calls from users.

Does anyone have any insights on this?

Comment: Could you please go through the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/call?view=graph-rest-1.0)? Try if that helps.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT, that is precisely the docs I inform in my post. It's under Cloud comunications. It seems to provide information from a specific call record, but there is no api to list all calls from a specific user.

Comment: Currently we don't have any API to list call records. Could you please raise a user voice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/)?

Comment: > "Could you please raise a user voice here?" (C)

Cannot open the link. But this feature is really helpful! We want it too.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/5394 -> just for reference. Github issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one for getting the teams user activity report:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D7')?$format=application/json&$top=2000
```

The `period` argument can be `D7`, `D30`, or `D90`.